# Why isn't askubuntu.com secure?

Tags: feature-request

I notice there is a secure connection when I login to stackExchange, but it goes away after I login to askubuntu.com. Why isn't askubuntu also running with encryption?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites, http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: SSL does work on the site but it's not forced on. If I had to guess why, I'd say they aren't ready to fight people uploading images to non-https servers and convert the backlog of images. I'm not SE though. That and IE+XP support (doesn't support SNI) which can make hosting a ballache.

Comment: @Oli: They could at least have a `Always use HTPPS version of this site` button which people could select and would place a cookie in their browser which would mean that they would have the HTTPS site as their default while using that browser. That would at least be a good starter.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda *I* think it should be always on, I was just suggesting reasons why SE might not want to yet.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess it may be something to do with the login page's link (even from HTTPS askubuntu) is

```
https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2faskubuntu.com%2f
```

wherease if you change it to

```
https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2faskubuntu.com%2f
```

It should go back to the HTTPS page. This probably could be implemented in the HTTPS version of site. dunno.

(Checked in clean session of Firefox, though it somehow logged me out of another one)